# Joining Table attribute to Map attributes without matching properties

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, file-geodatabase, attribute-joins, table

I have a [Dataset](https://ftp.inovum-dev.de/?u=BJbC&p=kCem) (10Gb) that I imported to QGIS 3.22.

It contains multiple tables and maps.

The first map categorizes land usage (HWRM_HWRK_LN) and I was able to attribute a color gradient.

The four remaining maps represent flooding depth depending on probability.
Ut_hq010, for example, represents the depth for a flood level occurring statistically every 10 years; ut_hq050 every 50 years and so on.

These maps only have one Feature count as opposed to the first map wich counts thousands.

Each of these four flood depth maps comes with four tables containing various attributes and information.

My problem is that I don't know how to join tables attributes to the maps in order to show these flooding depth.

Keep in mind that all attribute tables are not editable.

Edit: Fixed the download link.

[image: Red area should appear nuanced]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I doubt if people will want to download a 10 GB example.  It would help if you could create a smaller download sample that still contains your issue.

Comment: @StuSmith Ok, I'll try to separate one of the four maps as they are almost identical. Is there a prefered format for people to work with ? Also what would be the best way to export Tables and Vector layers in a single file ?

Comment: It appears that your data is stored as a File Geodatabase (FGDB).  I'd propose that you make small selections of your current data and export it to a new FGDB.